# QnAMessage score not logged to bot telemetry

Tags: javascript, azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I've created a bot using javascript and the botbuilder-ai package. I've added telemetry to the bot and it's logging the properties except the **score**.
Checking the source code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/09f9d6318016ae5ca7d69d0781e4d5ade7dee785/libraries/botbuilder-ai/src/qnaMaker.ts#L334) I can see that it's added as a metric but I can't find it in customEvents - 'QnaMessage' nor under customMetrics, if it's supposed to be there.

Can someone guide me as to where the score is logged?
I need the score to create some queries for my dashboard.

The score is not present in customDimensions as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Hmm...I too just plugged in App Insights into my QnAMaker bot, and see what you're talking about. It looks like in the SDK where you linked, if you look into fillQnAEvent() method, you can see that all of the properties show up in customDimensions in the Azure portal, however score is saved as a telemetryMetric. Have you figured out yet how to query for telemetryMetrics associated with the event yet? I'm going to ask a co-worker to see if they could help as well..

Comment: @Zeryth: No, I still haven't figured out how to query telemetryMetrics. To my displeasure I've managed to implement my logic by using the score available in the QnAMaker service's logs than the bot logs. Please let me know if you find a solution for this.